# laravel clear and item in collection data

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and have a query but need to modify the data structure of the collection before returning it. I'm trying to clear the orders by setting them to an empty array but it doesn't clear (I still get all the original results in the returned json). However, if I unset the orders it works. In fact no matter what I set $res->product->orders to it doesn't work unless I unset it first.

```
$stores = array();    

foreach($data as $key => $res) {

           // This is a hacky way to clear the orders but it works
           $orders = array();
           unset($res->product->orders);
           $res->product->orders = $orders;

           // This is the way I would have done it but it doesn't work
           $res->product->orders = array();

           $stores[$res->store_id]['name'] = $res->product->store_name;
           $stores[$res->store_id]['data'][] = $res;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the data contained in $data

Comment: unfortunately the data is confidential but it looks like a normal collection object and I'm getting the product

Answer (score 0):

You can try collections transform any laravel 5.3 will return [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections) in both query bulider, éloquent

```
$data->transform(function($item) {
    return $item->product->orders = []; //I'm not sure here Product is object here?
});
```

Comment: this replaces the whole $item with an empty array. The product object is available but not returned in tact.